# Grails GORM find by value inside map of Domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am using Grails 2.2.4 and having one Domain contains value as map and I want to find domain object using key of map. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
Student.groovy
package com.grails

import java.util.Map;

class Student {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Map address
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When My application are run I can see that Grails application create tables in database are as follow:

```
1) first table 
 student
    id
    version
    first_name
    last_name
    indexes

2) second table
 student_address
    address
    addres_idx
    addres_elt
```

When I save Domain as:

```
def std = new Student()
std.firstName = 'Piyush'
std.lastName = 'Chaudhari'
std.address = [city:'Surat',state:'Gujarat',pincode:'38001']
std.save(flash:true)
```

values are insert in database as follow:

```
student table
ID  VERSION     FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME  
1     0         Piyush          Chaudhari
```

student_address table

```
ADDRESS     ADDRESS_IDX     ADDRESS_ELT  
1            city             Surat
1            state            Gujarat
1            pincode          38001
```

**Now, I want data or row using GORM like Student.findBy_____ or Student.findAllBy______
where 'city' = surat**

Any one can help me to resolved this issue?

Comment: I don't think that you can do this with maps

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Student.findBy<FieldName1>And<FieldName2> (<FieldNameParameter1>, <FieldNameParameter2>)
```

Or Either:`

```
Student.list().find { it.address.city == 'Surat' }
Student.list().findAll { it.address.city == 'Surat' }
```

`

Comment: second: actually needs to load everything in memory to later do the search, first: dynamic finders won't work with maps AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Define an address class, and then add an address field to the student class (this will change how your tables are mapped in the database):

```
class Student {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    Address address
    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Address {
    String city
    String state
    String pincode
}
```

Address should be another entity in your domain, not a map of values. Remember that Grails GROM is an ORM, so you should design your domain using a OOP model in order to take advantage of the dynamic finders and criterias for doing queries.

With those changes in place, you can now use a simple criteria:

```
def students = Student.withCriteria{
  'address'{
    eq('city', 'surat')
  }
}
```

More information about criterias in the grails docs:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#criteria

If you want to use Dynamic finders, you will have to get all the address with city = 'surat' and then use a findByAddressInList(...). But i think that in this case, criterias is a better approach

Comment: I have already try with this one but getting error:

collection was not an association: com.grails.Student.address. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.MappingException: collection was not an association: com.grails.Student.address
 at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1685)

Comment: The problem is that you defined address as a map. You need to define an association, i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I know this association very well but I have faced this type of problem so I am finding solution to fix this issue.

Comment: If you can detail the problem a little bit better maybe we can find another approach, but using a map for that is not a good idea because yu will be forced to filter the map like @meurer suggested, or use plain SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can search things like this using maps.

Maybe you can do this:

```
def students = Student.list()
def result = students.each { student -> student.address.city == 'Surat' }
println("Resultado" + result)
```

But this is a very bad way to do this kind of things